# Put value in minimum ID record in SQL data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where I'm trying to get the following result: CategoryType should be set to 0 for the member record with the lowest categoryID and 1 if that ID is NULL.  CategoryType is not a field from the table so it should be added via a Case statement.  I wrote a script using the Row_Number() window function to organize the records but I'm not sure how to put a 0 for the lowest record.  I tried using a Min(Case) statement but that didn't work.

```
declare @t table(memberid int, lastname varchar(50), firstname varchar(50),     categoryid int)
insert into @t
values(1, 'Jones', 'Tom', 2), (1, 'Jones', 'Tom', 4),
      (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 3), (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 4),
      (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 5),
      (3, 'Smith', 'Jack', NULL);
```

This is the result I'm trying to get:

```
MemberID     LastName    FirstName    CategoryID    CategoryType
  1           Jones        Tom            2             0
  1           Jones        Tom            4            NULL 
  2           Hanson       Ron            3             0
  2           Hanson       Ron            4            NULL
  2           Hanson       Ron            5            NULL
  3           Smith        Jack          NULL           1
```

Comment: How does Jones and Hanson both have 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when categoryid is null
             then 1
             when row_number() over (partition by memberid order by categoryid) = 1
             then 0
        end) as categorytype
from @t t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04646e58e44b5cbc6e9989c1abc80600) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Comment: @jackstraw22 There is a mistake here, why the results are not the same as your expected results? even with an `ORDER BY` clause? Still you say "Perfect"

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
  select *
    ,case
        when categoryid is null then 1 
        when FIRST_VALUE(categoryid) over (partition by memberid order by categoryid) = categoryid then 0 else null 
        end as x
  from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
  SELECT *,CASE WHEN categoryid IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY categoryid ORDER BY memberid) = 1 
                THEN 0
   END CategoryType FROM @T
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier to read/extend (if needed):

```
SELECT a.MemberID,a.LastName,a.FirstName,a.CategoryID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN a.rn = 1 AND a.CategoryID IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN a.rn = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
     END AS [CategoryType]
FROM (
    SELECT t.MemberID,t.LastName,t.FirstName,t.CategoryID
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.MemberID ORDER BY t.CategoryID) AS [rn]
    FROM @t t
) a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Can Help You

```
declare @t table(memberid int, 
                 lastname varchar(50), 
                 firstname varchar(50),     
                 categoryid int)

insert into @t
values(1, 'Jones', 'Tom', 2), 
      (1, 'Jones', 'Tom', 4),
      (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 3), 
      (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 4),
      (2, 'Hanson', 'Ron', 5),
      (3, 'Smith', 'Jack', NULL)

      Select 
        A.*, 
        Case When a.categoryid is null Then '1' 
             When b.categoryid is not null Then '0' Else null End CategoryType 
      From @t A
      Left Join (
          Select memberid, min(categoryid) categoryid From @t 
          Group By memberid
      ) B On B.memberid = A.memberid and B.categoryid = A.categoryid
```

[image]